# zsh: command not found: pg_dump on mac OS Big Sur

Tags: postgresql, macos, psql, macos-big-sur, pg-dump

I'm on OSX Big Sur - 11.4 (20F71), and I really need to export a simple database out of my local set up.

`pg_dump` is not working for me.

I kept getting :

> zsh: command not found: pg_dump

I got the psql command to run because I added an alias

> psql='/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/bin/psql -p5432'

Any hint for to get the pg_dump to work ?

Comment: Really? [zsh path](https://koenwoortman.com/zsh-add-directory-to-path/)

Answer (score 9):

## Thanks to this [link](http://%20https://koenwoortman.com/zsh-add-directory-to-path/)

From  ***@Adrian Klaver***

https://koenwoortman.com/zsh-add-directory-to-path/

I was able to understand more about `$PATH`

Organized my `$PATH` like so :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/opt/curl/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/mysql/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/bin
```

The actual solution is :

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/13/bin
```

I can run pg_dump now :

```
➜  Sites pg_dump                                                                                                            
--
-- PostgreSQL database dump
--

-- Dumped from database version 13.1
-- Dumped by pg_dump version 13.1

SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;
SET idle_in_transaction_session_timeout = 0;
SET client_encoding = 'UTF8';
SET standard_conforming_strings = on;
SELECT pg_catalog.set_config('search_path', '', false);
SET check_function_bodies = false;
SET xmloption = content;
SET client_min_messages = warning;
SET row_security = off;

--
-- PostgreSQL database dump complete
--
```

Comment: In order to always use the latest version of Postgres it's better to use the "latest" linked folder as such:
export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/lastest/bin

Answer (score 3):

For some reason, the accepted answer didn't work for me. I had to use the following for PSQL 15:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/Library/PostgreSQL/15/bin
```

Answer (score 1):

If you use the symbolic link 'latest' directory rather than the version number the PATH won't break when you update to the latest version of the Postgress.app e.g. the followning:

> export PATH=$PATH:/Applications/Postgres.app/Contents/Versions/*latest*/bin